# Associate values in two arrays of unequal length

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array of three colors like so:

```
['blue', 'green', 'red']
```

And I have an array of hats:

```
['fedora', 'bowler', 'top hat', '10 gallon']
```

How can I assign a color to each hat and when I've run out of colors start over from the beginning? So that:

```
fedora =  blue
bowler = green
top hat = red
10 gallon = blue
```

Comment: Starting very simple: One way would be to have two counters, one for the first array and one for the second. If the first counter reaches `array1.length`, you reset it to `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the hats. Within the loop you can use the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) (similar to a "modulo" operator in other languages) to get the correct `color` index for each `hat` index.

```
var hats = ['fedora', 'bowler', 'top hat', '10 gallon'],
    colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'];


for (var i = 0; i < hats.length; i++) {
    var hat = hats[i]; // this would be hats[0], then [1], [2], [3], [4], ...
    var color = colors[i % colors.length]; // this would be colors[0], then [1], [2], [0], [1], ...

    console.log(hat + ' = ' + color);
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgy0pomb/)

The operator provides the remainder when `i` is divided by `colors.length`. For i = `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...`, `i % colors.length` would be `0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...` (i.e. how many are left over when you divide `i` by 3) which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Say the longest array has length = 4, and shortest = 3

Then you use the 4 as index for looping the big one, and you use `index % 3` for the shortest one.